# How to implement type that allows to extend generic function arguments

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement type that allows user to add some arguments to type of already defined function.
For example:

```
function sourceFunction(a: number, b: string): number {
    return a;
};
const extendedFunction: ExtendFunction<typeof sourceFunction, [boolean?]> = (a, b, flag) => {
    //where a: number, b: string, flag: boolean | undefined
    return a;
}
```

I've implemented something that almost does the job:

```
export type ExtendFunction<TFunction extends (...args: any) => any, TParameters extends any[]> = (
  ...args: [...Parameters<TFunction>, ...TParameters]
) => ReturnType<TFunction>;
```

however type fails to parse properly functions that are a generic ones, for example:

```
function sourceFunction<T>(a: T, b: string): T {
    return a;
};

const extendedFunction: ExtendFunction<typeof sourceFunction, [boolean?]> = (a, b, flag) => {
    //a is undefined instead of T
    return a;
}
```

Is there a way to make `ExtendFunction` type recognise that passed function is a generic one and in the example above returned value should be of type T?

Comment: Not directly, no. TypeScript lacks true higher order generic types in the type system.  The closest you can get is to use [the support for composing generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), but that needs to happen with function *values* and not just *types*.  So you need to obtain (or pretend to obtain) functions of the appropriate type, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NlXxlN). It becomes the type you want you can see how you have to drop down to the value level.

Comment: (see prev comment).  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer post explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: yup, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript can't really express the manipulation of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function types at the type level like this.  The language lacks the sort of higher kinded types necessary to do so.  So [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like [`Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) will erase type parameters when `T` is generic.   There are various feature requests asking for support for improvements: the "standard" higher-kinded types request is at [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) although it's not clear if that covers this use case.  In any case it's not part of the language.

The closest you can currently get in TypeScript is to drop from the type level to the value level and use the support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions).  That is, you can't take a generic function type `F`, pass it to a generic type `Transform<>`, and get a transformed generic function type out as `Transform<F>`.  But you *can* take a generic function *value* `f` of type `F`, pass it into another generic *function* `transform()`, and get a transformed generic function *value* out whose type is equivalent to your desired `Transform<F>`.

That is, we can drop `ExtendedFunction<F, X>` down to something like `extendFunction<A, X, R>` (where `A` and `R` are the arguments and return type of `F`, respectively):

```
function extendFunction<A extends any[], X extends any[], R>(
    f: (...args: A) => R, x: X): (...args: [...A, ...X]) => R {
    return f as any
}
```

So that function accepts a (possibly generic) function `f` of type `(...args: A) => R` and a tuple of type `X`, and returns a new (possibly generic) function of type `(...args: [...A, ...X]) => R`.  Which gives you this:

```
function sourceFunction<T>(a: T, b: string): T {
    return a;
};

let extendedFunction = extendFunction(sourceFunction, null! as [boolean?]);
// let extendedFunction: <T>(a: T, b: string, args_2?: boolean | undefined) => T

extendedFunction = (a, b, flag) => {
    return a;
}
```

You'll see that the types conform exactly to what you wanted.  Also, the actual implementation of `extendFunction` doesn't matter much (I just used `any` to suppress errors), since your goal is just to manipulate the type.

This sort of dropping from the type level to the value level is suitable for some use cases of higher-kinded function types, and not suitable for others.  It works well enough if you just want to transform a specific function type.  But as soon as you try to abstract over such an operation (e.g., mapping an object of generic methods to another object of related generic methods) you'll find that it just doesn't work.  Until and unless true type-level support appears, though, there isn't a perfect approach.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEBTAHrNkAmAxKOJSAHgEF0sdcBnFAQ0gE8BtAXQBoUANK7PPSZsuKAEoA+ABTAUclKABcKKQDp1DAE4BzWsvIBKFAF4J47hmU8DytRp16UrdavLcXPdkdPiUAb1l5TTRYcE1UUEYhFmAAXxAIGARkFFpEMOg0QiSSUgAVaQZlPO4AI2VaWE14SG0bFDz-QLlg0PDGAG44ruAAGxD+GjQCImTUY0G8bOJkKTSMrNGSbkhwXt6AQiinUsREfqYAfi8ugHpTlH7YSdxh6bHlfMLisoqqmu1uLV0AfQAmQ7KXb7NBMFAAHxQUFuoBqw28ZjyIEwAluIxyKQmUgYZW4oF6DDqJjMAXkKFaYVQDC68RAQA)